# How to turn an airplane 90 degrees right and left?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

**hello**. I'm making a mobile joystick game where I should fly a plane. So I wrote a script that works but the plane does not turn as I wanted. for example I want to turn completely to the right to do 90 degrees but the plane continues straight by moving a little to the right*your text*
*here is the script*

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlaneController : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Joystick joystick;
    public float forwardSpeed  = 15f;
    public float horizontalSpeed = 4f;
    public float verticalSpeed = 4f;
    public float smoothness = 5f;
    public float maxHorizontalRotation=0.1f;
    public float maxVerticalRotation = 0.06f;
    public float rotationSmoothness=5f;


    public Rigidbody rb;
    private float horizontalInput;
    private float verticalInput;
    public float forwardSpeedMultiplier= 100f;
    private float speedMultiplier=1000f;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        rb.GetComponent<Rigidbody>(); 
        
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetMouseButton(0) || Input.touches.Length !=0) {//celui la pour jouer avec le téléphone 
            horizontalInput = joystick.Horizontal;
            verticalInput= joystick.Vertical;
        
        }
        else // pour le pc 
        {
            horizontalInput=Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal");
            verticalInput=Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical");
        }
        HandlePlaneRotation();
    }
    private void FixedUpdate(){
        HandlePlaneMovement();
    }

    private void HandlePlaneMovement(){
        rb.velocity=new Vector3(

            rb.velocity.x,
            rb.velocity.y,
            forwardSpeed * forwardSpeedMultiplier * Time.deltaTime);

            float xVelocity= horizontalInput * speedMultiplier * horizontalSpeed*Time.deltaTime;
             float yVelocity= -verticalInput * speedMultiplier * verticalSpeed*Time.deltaTime;

             rb.velocity= Vector3.Lerp(
                rb.velocity,
                new  Vector3(xVelocity,yVelocity, rb.velocity.z),
                Time.deltaTime * smoothness);
            
    }
    private void HandlePlaneRotation(){
        float horizontalRotation = horizontalInput * maxHorizontalRotation;
        float verticalRotation = verticalInput *maxVerticalRotation ;

        transform.rotation = Quaternion.Lerp(
            transform.rotation,
            new Quaternion
            (verticalRotation,
            transform.rotation.y,
            horizontalRotation,
            transform.rotation.w),Time.deltaTime*rotationSmoothness
        );

    }
}
*Thank you* 




I want you to tell me what I should do to fix this problem.
I already tried several things but I couldn't.      
    
                Thank.
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, as I see in your code you are having a bit problem with how plane movement works.
first planes always have forward velocity so you don't need a joystick for handling that :
`rb.AddForce(transform.forward * speed, ForceMode.Impulse);`
But you can use the `JoyStick joyStick` for changing the forward vector of your plane (changing y Euler angle) and here is an example of doing that :

```
x = joyStick.Horizontal;
y = joyStick.Vertical;

yRot = Quaternion.LookRotation(Vector3.forward * y + Vector3.right * x, Vector3.up).eulerAngles.y;
```

It's a similar code as `Assets/Joystick Pack/Examples/JoystickPlayer.cs` but here we convert that force to a forward vector and use that for setting the Euler angle of an object.

Note: You can add some extra movement waves or noises to add more feeling to your plane movement.

Hope it was helpful.

Comment: Thank but me I need my airpalne turn 90 degrees

Comment: that code calculates the degree automatically